# Lots of 400 error in nginx access log

Tags: nginx

In ningx, there is lots of such error

```
2016-10-08T22:17:59+08:00       400     4949340343      1       171.115.135.59  -       -       0       184.741 -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949388175      1       123.161.64.75   -       -       0       95.150  -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949391030      1       117.136.79.8    -       -       0       92.027  -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949390990      1       183.32.54.196   -       -       0       92.094  -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949390978      1       223.255.14.242  -       -       0       0.000   -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949390964      1       219.137.65.23   -       -       0       0.000   -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949379439      1       1.204.197.60    -       -       0       110.331 -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949390909      1       183.162.132.146 -       -       0       0.000   -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949388082      1       183.23.173.27   -       -       0       95.234  -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949390892      1       221.238.245.20  -       -       0       0.000   -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
2016-10-08T22:17:58+08:00       400     4949339451      1       123.166.215.219 -       -       0       185.267 -       -       -       443     -       -       -       0       -       TLSv1.2 (NONE)  -       -       -
```

during such error happens, I saw the cpu iowait time increase from almost 0 to 70. And network traffic is decrease a little at the same time.

I am pretty sure the request line, request header are correct, because all request are sent from our client, not browser. Could anyone help, thanks in advance.

Add log format:

```
'$time_iso8601   $status $connection     $connection_requests    $remote_addr    $http_x_forwarded_for   $remote_user    $request_length $request_time   $request_method $server_protocol $http_host      $server_port    $uri    $args   $http_referer   $body_bytes_sent        $http_user_agent        $ssl_protocol   $ssl_cipher     $upstream_addr  $upstream_status$upstream_response_time';
```